# Adding tasks to G Suite users using a service account

Tags: google-tasks

I have a G Suite domain with working API access to the domain and calendars using a service account.

I'd like to be able to insert tasks in to the task lists of my users.

I'm looking at the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasklists/list

I can get "my own" tasklist like this:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists

I'd like to get other users's list. However I get 404 error when trying this:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/foo@example.com/lists

Any suggestions on how to get a users task lists?

Comment: Referencing another user appears to have been a feature in 2011:
https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/using-2-legged-oauth-with-google-tasks.html

Comment: did you get any answer o solution to this?